# Using an NSString to determine an input one character at a time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am making an app for the iPhone using Xcode and I think that Xcode is messing me up...
I have in the `ViewController.h`:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *passwordResult;

 - (IBAction)go:(id)sender;
```

and in the `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    A = @"A";

}

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {

    password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _passwordField.text];

    if (password == A) {
         _passwordResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", A];
         }
   }
```

This should print the capital letter 'A' to my label if the input is a capital 'A', right?
If not, How would I do this?

NOTE: I do not want to just copy the inputted phrase and print that, I want to make a password cracker application just to see if it works...

Comment: Oh the horror of those redundant `+stringWithFormat:` calls!

Comment: @CodaFi: I've seen worse: `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", anotherStr]];`

Comment: @dreamlax At least 4.6 will call you out on it.  Can't wait til those new compiler warnings get shipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (password == A)
```

use

```
if ([password isEqualToString:A])
```

Otherwise, you're only comparing pointers, not the contents of the strings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For string comparisons, use `[someString isEqualToString:anotherString]`

Using `==` will compare to see if both pointers point to the same object, not if they point to objects with the same contents. Even if both pointers contain the same string, that does not mean they point to the same object.

If two people both have the same car, and so have the same key to unlock it, both keys are not equal and will not open both cars; each will only open the car for which it was made. If one person has a car but has an extra key made, they are equal because they open the same car (object). You can think of the pointers in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As Rickay and trudyscousin have indicated, your test for equality should be `isEqualToString` not `==`.

And - as CodaFi and dreamlax are hinting, this line:

```
 _passwordResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", A];
```

contains some redundancy, as both A and _passwordResult.text are NSStrings, so you don't need to create an intermediary NSString:

```
_passwordResult.text = A;
```

will suffice.

A couple of other stylistic observations...

You have presumably declared your iVar "A" somewhere. I would recommend using a property declaration as you have done for your IBOutlets, and also giving it a better name.

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* aBetterNamedA`

You should also use accessor syntax even inside your object:

`self.aBetterNamedA`
`self.passwordResult.txt`

(the only exception to this should be your `init` and `dealloc` methods, which should address iVar directly).